# A tangent to ellipse $E_1$ intersects ellipse $E_2$ at $P$ and $Q$. Prove that the tangents to $E_2$ at $P$ and $Q$ are perpendicular to each other.

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

A tangent to the ellipse $x^2 + 4y^2 = 4$ meets the ellipse $x^2 + 2y^2 = 6$ at P and Q. Prove that tangents at $P$ and $Q$ of ellipse $x^2 + 2y^2 = 6$ are perpendicular to each other.

---

Let $E_1: \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{1} = 1$ and $E_2: \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{y^2}{3} = 1$ be the equation of the ellipses.

Let $R(h, k)$ be the point of tangent on $E_1$

Then let $L_1: y - k = m(x - h)$ be a line passing through two points $P$ and $Q$ on the outer ellipse. This line is tangential to $E_1$ at $R$.

To find the slope of the tangent at $R$ we take the derivative of $E_1$ at $R$.

$$m = \frac{-h}{4k}$$

$$y - k = \frac{-h}{4k}(x - h)$$
$$ h^2 + 4k^2 = 4ky + hx \tag{1}$$

We know that $R(h, k)$ satisfies $E_1$. Hence, $$h^2 + 4k^2 = 4 \tag{2}$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ implies, 
$$4ky + hx = 4 \tag{3}$$

$(3)$ is the equation of the tangent to $E_1$ at $R$.

I don't know how to proceed further.

---

I can think of various approaches, but can't work it out.

1. Proving that the point of intersection of the two tangents lies on a circle of diameter $PQ$. (We know that angle in a semicircle is $90$ degrees).
2. We can prove that product of slopes of the two tangents to $E_2$ is $-1$.

Comment: Solving a converse problem (given tangents to $P$ and $Q$ intersects at right angle then line $PQ$ has exactly $1$ point with inner ellipse) and revert the solution seems more easy, but needs to be worked out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known that the locus of points where two perpendicular tangent to the ellipse cross each other is a circle, called the [director circle of the ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_circle), whose radius is $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=3$ in our case.

We can then revert the proof: taken any point $(h,k)$ on the director circle (hence $h^2+k^2=9$), its chord of contact $PQ$ to ellipse $E_2$ has the [simple equation](https://www.cuemath.com/jee/important-results-on-tangents-and-chords-ellipses/)
$$
{hx\over6}+{ky\over3}=1
$$
and it then suffices to show that this line is tangent to ellipse $E_1$ for all values of $(h,k)$. In fact, substituting $y$ from the above equation into the equation of $E_1$ yields the resolvent equation
$$
\left({3\over2}x-h\right)^2=0
$$
with a single solution $x=2/3 h$. That completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to solve the converse problem (given tangents to $P$ and $Q$ intersects at right angle then line $PQ$ has exactly $1$ intersection point with inner ellipse) and revert the solution. 
Let $P(x_p,y_p)$ and $Q(x_q,y_q)$.
Performing implicit differentiation on $x^2+2y^2=6$ we have 
$$2x+4yy'=0\Rightarrow y'=\frac{-x}{2y},\,y\ne 0.$$
Then the tangets to the larger ellipse at $P,Q$ are, resp:
$$\frac{-x_p}{2y_p}(x-x_p)=(y-y_p)\hbox{ and }
\begin{cases}
x=x_q+2y_qt\\
y=y_q-x_qt
\end{cases}$$
The intersection:
$$-x_p(x_q+2y_qt-x_p)=2y_p(y_q-x_qt-y_p)$$
[$$y_p x_q - x_p y_q\ne0,\, t = \frac{-x_p^2 + x_p x_q - 2 y_p^2 + 2 y_p y_q}{2 (y_p x_q - x_p y_q)}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-a*%28c%2B2*d*t-a%29%3D2*b*%28d-c*t-b%29)
and the intersection point is $I=(x_q+2y_qt,y_q-x_qt)$. 
 Vectors $PI$ and $QI$, resp:
$$PI=(x_q-x_p+2y_qt,y_q-y_p-x_qt),\,QI=t(2y_q,-x_q)$$
And the inner (dot) product is $0$:
$$(x_q-x_p+2y_qt)\cdot 2y_q-(y_q-y_p-x_qt)x_q=0\Leftrightarrow$$
[$$\frac{(x_p x_q + 4 y_p y_q) (x_p x_q + 2 y_p y_q - x_q^2 - 2 y_q^2)}{2 (x_p y_q - y_p x_q)}=0$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*%28c-a%2B2*d*t%29*d-%28d-b-c*t%29*c+where+t+%3D+%28-a%5E2+%2B+a+c+-+2+b%5E2+%2B+2+b+d%29%2F%282+%28b+c+-+a+d%29%29)
Now we take $R$ on $PQ$: $R=uP+(1-u)Q$ and the intersection $x_R^2+4y_R^2=4$:
$$(ux_p+(1-u)x_q)^2+4(uy_p+(1-u)y_q)^2-4=0$$
is quadratic in terms of $u$ and it's discriminant
$$-16 (x_p^2 y_q^2 - x_p^2 - 2 x_p y_p x_q y_q + 2 x_p x_q + y_p^2 x_q^2 - 4 y_p^2 + 8 y_p y_q - x_q^2 - 4 y_q^2)$$
indeed [equals 0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Discriminant%5B-4+%2B+%28c*%281+-+u%29+%2B+a*u%29%5E2+%2B+4*%28d*%281+-+u%29+%2B+b*u%29%5E2%2C+u%5D+where+a%5E2%2B2*b%5E2%3D6%2C+c%5E2%2B2*d%5E2%3D6%2C+%28a*c+%2B+4*b*d%29*%28a*c+%2B+2*b*d+-+c%5E2+-+2*d%5E2%29%3D0). Don't know how wolframalpha did get there.
Now we see the converse is true with the additional results of [$u=\frac{-4}{x_p^2-12}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a*c+%2B+4*b*d%29*%28a*c+%2B+2*b*d+-+c%5E2+-+2*d%5E2%29%3D0%2C+a%5E2%2B2*b%5E2%3D6%2C+c%5E2%2B2*d%5E2%3D6%2C+%28u*a%2B%281-u%29*c%29%5E2%2B4*%28u*b%2B%281-u%29*d%29%5E2%3D4) and [$x_I^2+y_I^2=9$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28c%2B2*d*t%29%5E2%2B%28d-c*t%29%5E2+where+t+%3D+%28-a%5E2+%2B+a*c+-+2*b%5E2+%2B+2*b*d%29%2F%282*%28b*c+-+a*d%29%29%2C+%28a*c+%2B+4*b*d%29*%28a*c+%2B+2*b*d+-+c%5E2+-+2*d%5E2%29%3D0%2C+a%5E2%2B2*b%5E2%3D6%2C+c%5E2%2B2*d%5E2%3D6).
[image]
Now the original problem seems more simple:
1. We take arbitrary $R$ on the inner ellipse
2. Make tangent in $R$ intersect the outer ellipse in $P,Q$ (quadratic)
then either 3. compute $u=\frac{|RQ|}{|PQ|}$ and compare with $\frac{-4}{x_P^2-12}$
or 4. Intersect the tangents to the outer ellipse at $P,Q$ with $x^2+y^2=9$ and see there are $3$ distinct points, with two of them symmetrical thruogh $O(0,0)$ so the angle at the third point is right as two others form a diameter of $x^2+y^2=9$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(2\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ be the point of tangency on $E_1$. The slope of this tangent line will be 
$$t_A=-\frac{\cot \theta}{2}.$$
The equation of the tangent line $\ell$ at $A$ on ellipse $E_1$ is given by:
$$\ell: x\cos \theta+2y \sin \theta=2. \tag{1}$$

Let $P=(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ be the points on $E_2$ where the tangent $\ell$ intersects $E_2$.

Consider the intersection of $E_2$ ($x^2+2y^2=6$) and $\ell$ (equ (1)):

1. We can get a quadratic equation in $x$ which will be of the form:
   $$x^2(1+\sin^2\theta)-4x \sin \theta +4(1-3\sin^2\theta)=0.$$

This should have roots $x_1,x_2$ (the $x-$coordinates of $P$ and $Q$). Using Viete's relation,
$$\color{red}{x_1x_2 = \frac{4(1-3\sin^2 \theta)}{1+\sin^2\theta}=\frac{-4(2-3\cos^2 \theta)}{1+\sin^2\theta}}.$$

2. We can get a quadratic equation in $y$ which will be of the form:
   $$y^2(1+\sin^2\theta)-4y \cos \theta +(2-3\cos^2\theta)=0.$$

This should have roots $y_1,y_2$ (the $y-$coordinates of $P$ and $Q$). Using Viete's relation,
$$\color{blue}{y_1y_2 = \frac{(2-3\cos^2 \theta)}{1+\sin^2\theta}}=\color{green}{\frac{-x_1x_2}{4}}.$$

Slope of tangents at $P$ and $Q$ are
$$t_P=\frac{-x_1}{2y_1} \quad \text{ and } \quad t_Q=\frac{-x_2}{2y_2}.$$
For these tangents to be perpendicular, **we want to show that**
$$t_p \cdot t_Q=-1 \implies \boxed{\frac{x_1x_2}{4y_1y_2}=-1}.$$ 
Plug in the expressions for $x_1x_2$ and $y_1y_2$ and you get the answer.